# Retrieve Firestore Document count from query to use in UIcollectionView cell count, Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller where I need to retrieve the number of documents so I can generate and exact number of cells in UIcollectionView. The issue I'm having is that I can never seem to retrieve the count before it is used by UIcollectionview data source method. It always returns nil.

**Is there a general way to force the code to retrieve this number and pass it to the UIcollectionviewDatasource method before it can return a nil value?**

I'm new to coding in general so my apologies if this is a simple answer. But I have timing issues all the time since I started using cloud based storage in my apps"

```
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()


         itemEntryRef.order(by: "_id", descending: false).getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
                    print("query attempted")


                    if let err = err {
                        // There was an error
                        print("query failed")
                        print(err)

                    } else {

                        print("query successful")

                        print(querySnapshot!.count)
                        self.itemCount = querySnapshot!.count

                    }
            }

     //UIcollectionView DataSource
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return self.itemCount
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = ledgerCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: testString, for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "translucent")
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: It is not that will always return nil, the problem is that by the time Firestore downloaded the data the collectionView was already displayed. Add a didSet observer to itemCount. Something like this `var itemCout : Int = 0 { didSet { self.collectionView.reloadData() } }`